# Adding sin(x + a) + sin(x + b)

Tags: analysis, trigonometry

I'm trying to prove
$$\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R} \exists c,d,e\in \mathbb{R}: f(x):=\sin(x+a) + \sin(x+b) = c \sin(x+d) + e$$

I attempted using $\sin(s) = \frac{e^{is} - e^{-is}}{2i}$ and ended up with an equality similar to $e^{ix} - \alpha e^{-ix}$, where usually $\alpha \neq 1$, which indicates that this way is impossible.

I also looked at the series expansion of sine, but had no idea where to even start.

This is part of a larger problem, and likely not required in the solution, but I am curious how this can be solved.

Comment: To be honest , I don't know why you need the extra $e$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you get access to calculus to do this?

Your function $f$ is given by $$f(x)=\sin(x+a)+\sin(x+b)$$

And you propose that it is equal to $g$ given by $$g(x)=c\sin(x+d)+e$$

First of all, the midline of $f$ is clearly(?) at $y=0$, so if this will work, $e$ must be $0$.

Now note that both functions satisfy $y''=-y$. So if they have the same value at $x=0$ and derivative at $x=0$, then they are indeed the same function. To make this happen requires
$$\begin{align}
\sin(a)+\sin(b)=c\sin(d)\\
\cos(a)+\cos(b)=c\cos(d)
\end{align}$$

Which is a system of equations from which you could eliminate $c$ to solve for $d$ in terms of $a$ and $b$. And then you could solve for $c$ too.

This results in $$\sin(x+a)+\sin(x+b)=\frac{\sin(a)+\sin(b)}{\sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{\sin(a)+\sin(b)}{\cos(a)+\cos(b)}\right)\right)}\sin\left(x+\arctan\left(\frac{\sin(a)+\sin(b)}{\cos(a)+\cos(b)}\right)\right)$$

(And the trig(inverse trig) parts could be simplified using $\sin(\arctan(z))=\frac{z}{\sqrt{1+z^2}}$.)

Comment: What is the downvoter's objection?

Comment: I down voted the answer because this is sorcery. Just kidding,  I accidentally clicked the down arrow instead of the up arrow. I don't know why I can't up vote it again. I will though, after 6 minutes or so...

Comment: Hmm, can't seem to up vote. Vote locked in. I'll +1 in the comments.

Comment: I just verified this for myself. Good and easy solution!

Comment: @PandaBear Oh OK. I don't care about the rep, just wanted to know why.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to prove this to yourself would be to choose special points like $x = \pi + a$ and $x = -b$, and so on, and solve for $c,d,e$.  After having solved for your constants, you can then go and verify your answer with as many points as you want (or, as said above, by using the addtion formulae).

I will hint that it will be easiest to use your initial equation and its first derivative.

Comment: Solving it this way seems to get quite complicated quickly. Are you using the trigo identities heavily or is there some trick to it?

Comment: @mafutrct: I have to admit that it's been years since I've done this, but I have solved this identity this way when proving circuit results to class.

Comment: I will say that choosing those particular points is potentially not optimal.  The key is to get the sine to take known values.  It might also be prudent to shift your overall equation before you start, so you can eliminate $a$ or $b$, i.e., by defining $z = x+a$, and then defining  $\beta = b -a$, and $\delta = d - a$ so you have fewer constants to worry about.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a sensible idea

Answer (score 0):

Don't use complex exponentials, just expand everything using the addition formula for sine and group terms alike.

Comment: You mean $\sin(x+y) = \sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y$?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I suggested.

Comment: Could you show a few steps? I'm stuck in line 3 already.